# Amazon RDS Multi-AZ Failover

Tags: amazon-rds

Am considering the RDS Oracle product using Multi-AZ. One thing I can't find - if your primary instance goes away and you failover to the secondary instance, do you ever go back to the primary? Or does the secondary become primary, and another instance (perhaps your old primary) then become secondary? Does RDS automatically start a secondary instance for you and ensure that the secondary is up to date automatically? Or are you just running on one instance until you intervene manually?

Also - what type of latency hit can I expect to take given the synchronous updates?

Thanks...

Answer (score 3):

After a Failover, a "recovery" action is performed on the old primary server. It will be recovered OR it will be replaced. What is the algorithm that decides this is not made public by AWS.

Once the failed node is recovered/replaced, a "sync" action with the current primary node kicks in and data is sync'd.

From here on, the recovered node  (Old primary) will remain secondary node until another failover happens.

Comment: Also i have a query how, if my primary RDS dbinstance is in N.Virginia region then how can I find where the secondary DBinstance resides ?

Answer (score 0):

I got this answered by @faisal Khan in AWS repost.
https://repost.aws/questions/QU4DYhqh2yQGGmjE_x0ylBYg/what-happens-after-failover-in-rds

Yes, upon RDS Multi-AZ failover the failed primary instance is brought back up as the new standby instance to reinstate the high availability of your database.

To elucidate the above-mentioned:

The failover process is typically completed within 60-120 seconds where the standby instance is promoted as the new primary instance allowing you to resume your DB activities in the shortest amount of time.

While in the background, the failed primary instance is diagnosed by the RDS internal health monitoring system and remediation actions are taken based on the detected fault. The remediation action may involve simply rebooting the faulty instance to even replacement of the hardware depending on the detected fault. Once the old primary node is recovered, it is brought back up as the new Standby instance ensuring your DBs high-availability.

The recovery time of the failed node may vary upon the type of fault and the recovery process applied. Also, recovery time largely depends on the DB workload at the time of crash as RDS would perform data recovery and roll-back any uncommitted transactions eliminating any data inconsistencies across the nodes while providing you a single-box experience.

References:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/amazon-rds-under-the-hood-multi-az/

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.MultiAZSingleStandby.html#Concepts.MultiAZ.Failover